# Canopy package manager install button missing

Tags: python, canopy

I installed the last version of Canopy, with academic license, anda as far as I know, I should be able to update the packages, the problem is that once i select the package I'm attempting to install it shows it's versions, but won't show the installation button, neither with the free(core) packages as numpy and pandas...if someone could explain me why is that...my first guess would be the license, but it would still allow me to update the core packages...
Thanks for Your time...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qET7B.png)

Comment: Your interface is different to mine. However, you are on the "Installed" tab so surely it's logical that there would be no install button in a list of packages _already_ installed? You should be able to update it on the update tab.

Comment: yeah, thanks for answering! but in any tab(updates,installed, available) it looks the same, no button to install/unistall packages, I've already unistalled canopy, and installed over again, logged out and restarted and logged again, but the button keeps missing =/s

Comment: I actually find the package manager to be a pain to use anyway (even though it's stated as a convenience). Assuming you're on Windows you could always: open `cmd` and do `pip install wheel`. Then download the appropriate binary file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Then in the directory it downloaded in. hold SHIFT and right click, "Open terminal window here" and type `pip install <full_file_name_of_downloaded_file>`. So much easier and for some packages there's sometimes no other sane way to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have previous versions of Canopy installed? Uninstalling and reinstalling Canopy doesn't affect your installed package set (because the Canopy application and the User Python installation are connected but distinct). I would suggest *not* Canopy reinstalling again, but rather doing a full reset of your User Python environment by deleting the User Python directory as described in [this KB article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy).